# Is there still 500 entities limit for db.put() operation?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

Is there still 500 entities limit for db.put() operation on GAE ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't find any relevant documentation, but I tried 1000 at once and it worked fine.

Comment: it did not worked for me - com.google.cloud.datastore.DatastoreException: cannot write more than 500 entities in a single call

Answer (score 2):

The limit still exists (as recent as today- 6-Jan-2019).

I got the error "    "message": "com.google.cloud.datastore.DatastoreException: cannot write more than 500 entities in a single call"
" today.

Documentation also reveals that. Reference : https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/limits has 
"Maximum number of entities that can be passed to a Commit operation in the Cloud Datastore API 500"

Answer (score 0):

I think there are no limit of a number of entities, just a limit of 1 mega per api request.